# Changing climatizer filter in Cordoba 2005

Tags: ac, cabin-filter

How do I change the climatizer air filter in a 2005 Cordoba (2nd series I believe)?

I know for sure it's under the passenger seat, because I saw once a mechaning changing it. I want to do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is somewhere behind the gloves box.
This is not hard to do: (Photos extract from a foreigner language)

3 screws:

[image: http://up.autotitre.com/mini/06117549b3.jpg]

Push on clips marqued green, unmount the plastic cover by pulling it to the right, hold it at the red point.

[image]

There is two filters, you need to extract them one by one, they have a special position, you got to fold it a bit for enter them, this is normal (!)

[image]